# How to create ip address and port into NSData to work with

Tags: objective-c, sockets

I am working with a library called `GCDAsyncUDPSocket` and there is method that required me to pass the IP address and port as `NSData`.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the header file:

```
 * Binds the UDP socket to the given address, specified as a sockaddr structure wrapped in a NSData object.
 * 
 * If you have an existing struct sockaddr you can convert it to a NSData object like so:
 * struct sockaddr sa  -> NSData *dsa = [NSData dataWithBytes:&remoteAddr length:remoteAddr.sa_len];
 * struct sockaddr *sa -> NSData *dsa = [NSData dataWithBytes:remoteAddr length:remoteAddr->sa_len];
```

So, you need a `sockaddr`:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

struct sockaddr_in ip;
ip.sin_family = AF_INET;
ip.sin_port = htons(6003);
inet_pton(AF_INET, "0.0.0.0", &ip.sin_addr);

NSData * discoveryHost = [NSData dataWithBytes:&ip length:ip.sin_len];
```

Here's some documentation on `sockaddr` - http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/sockaddr_inman.html

Comment: With iOS 7.1 SDK in Xcode 5.1.1 this code seems to need some tweaking. `inet_pton()` appears to be declared in `<arpa/inet.h>` which you will need in addition to `<netinet/in.h>` (for the `sockaddr` struct), and the `sa_len` member being used in the call to `-[NSData dataWithBytes:length]` should be `sin_len` (not sure if that was originally a typo or a change in the SDK).

Comment: You can't use `ip.sin_len` without having set it yourself. It's not magically initialized. You have to initialize it. You can set it to `sizeof(ip)`.